# PyQt5, : "_MEI" path errors in pyinstaller py to exe

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

**First, I am a Korean Student. So I'm not good at English. Sorry, Please excuse me.**

I'm Using PyQt5 and pyinstaller. I made exe file using this code: `pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --paths "C:/Users/jun/Desktop/lee/Programing/python/dll" --hidden-import "nbt.world"  "C:/Users/jun/Desktop/lee/Programing/python/Auto_Submit_dev1.py"`

but I can't execute the exe file with this error.

[image]

I checked many similar questions and answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile), It doesn't work tho.

Below is part of my code:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
        print(base_path)
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
        


    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

macUI = resource_path("autosubmit.ui")

Ui_MainWindow = uic.loadUiType(macUI)[0]

class MainDialog(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
```

How can I execute the exe file? (.py is working and .UI file and .py file is in the same folder)

Comment: you must add .ui file with pyinstaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exe file does not find autosubmit.ui file
add this -->     --add-data="autosubmit.ui;."

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --add-data="autosubmit.ui;." --paths "C:/Users/jun/Desktop/lee/Programing/python/dll" --hidden-import "nbt.world"  "C:/Users/jun/Desktop/lee/Programing/python/Auto_Submit_dev1.py"
```